# How would I add this library to a rails project? https://github.com/petedmarsh/foaas-client

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

What is the best way to add this to rails so I have access to it's functions from within M's, V's, and C's?

Comment: Not sure if serious...

Comment: Totally serious.  Haha.  I'm a noob. I only want to use this library for customers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is a serious question, but...

Add it to your Gemfile:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'
gem 'foaas-client'
```

Load it in an initializer, `config/initializers/foaas.rb`:

```
FOAAS = Foaas::Client.new
```

`bundle` in your terminal

In your view, controller, model, etc.:

```
FOAAS.off('Bob', 'Alice')
```

Comment: Nice! Thanks. Didn't realize it was in sweet sweet Gem format.  Was  trying to figure out how to autoload it but being a gem is perfect. Trying to overthink it!  Thanks for you help.

Comment: No problem! This might not be the best solution since `FOAAS` won't get garbage collected, but for what sounds like a fun project, it should get the job done. Otherwise, instantiating and/or caching the client on demand might be a good approach.